# Set Name of report for export in C#

Tags: c#, report

I'm coming close to pulling all my hair out on this! Seems like it should be really easy to set the name which appears in the export dialog of the reporting tool in C# during runtime but I can't figure out how to do this.

I would be eternally grateful for any help on this matter.

Comment: Are you using Crystal report?

Comment: No I'm using the other report view in .NET (the one for which you make an .rdlc file).

Answer (score 0):

you can rename your rdlc report in solution  explorer or set name in xml file..